# Serialize Sources with conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-pipes, network-conduit, zip-conduit

I'm looking for a function that could have this signature :

```
serializeSources :: Monad m => [Source m a] -> Source m a
```

Having x sources with the same value produced that are serialized into 1 stream...First produced first received by downstream components... ZipSources would be the closest that I have found but I don't want the "zipList" behaviour as you can imagine in my context ...

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't just using [`sequence_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:sequence_) work?